# Getting a Linecast to pass through a point but continue onwards infinitley

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, raycasting

I am having an issue with linecasting in Unity 2D. What I am trying to do is have a linecast go from the player, through the cursor on screen, and then indefinitely (or for a large time, say times 10). I have made successful attempts at having a `Debug.Drawline` pass from the player and stop at the location of the mouse. It looks like this:

[image]

Do note that the location of my cursor is on the upper left corner of that block. below is the code I use to accomplish this:

```
    mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
    Debug.DrawLine(new Vector2 (player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y+32), new Vector2 (mousePos.x, mousePos.y), Color.green);
```

Do note that the +32 is used to center the drawline to my characte. However, if I were to multiply the mousePos vector by 2, I get this offset in the drawcast (and also linecast).

[image]

Once again my cursor is on the upper left corner of the block. Why is this offset behaving so oddly?

Comment: @Loop I have tried that, and this: Debug.DrawLine(new Vector2 (player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y+32), new Vector2 (mousePos.x, mousePos.y)*2, Color.green); Both have the same affect.

Comment: Sorry for deleting prev comment. Internet connection at my location is not stable so I though it couldnt reach you. But I notice you are ScreenToWorldPoint without z parameter => You will get the camera position. Did you aware of it? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/331558/screentoworldpoint-not-working.html

Comment: @Loop that link doesn't seem to be helping me. I believe I might be in need of some trigonometry. I found the angle between where the mouse is and the origin of my character with respect to the positive x axis and tried using the cosine and sine of this angle to feed into my debug.drawline. No luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

Linecast means from one point to another point. You seem to describe raycast which goes from one point in a direction.

So in your case you'd take the direction from the player to the mouse pointer, normalize that and use infinity as distance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but as it has already been pointed out I think you should use raycast instead. For example:

```
var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint((Vector2)Input.mousePosition);
var playerPos = (Vector2)player.transform.position;
var direction = (playerPos - mousePos).normalized;
Debug.DrawRay(new Vector2(playerPos.x, playerPos.y + 32), direction, Color.green);
```